# How to check if a new process started in windows?

Tags: python, windows, process, psutil

I was trying to write a program that notifies me whenever a new process starts.

My first idea is to use **psutil** in python and check for the number of processes in a background process using **sched** to have it check every 5 seconds.

However to get the process Id of the new process is kind of complicated because I would have to save the list of all running processes and compare it with the new list after five seconds. Then find the differences and get the id of the new processes.

This seems to be really ineffective.

Does anybody know a more effective way to check for new processes and get their process Id when they start? I guess the best way would be to learn how to do this in windows api but python would be much easier.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you convert the list of process id's into a python `set` object, you can compare the new set to the old set with a single function call.  Your "really ineffective" approach requires roughly one line of code.

Comment: You think it wont slow the system down if i compare two sets with 300+ objects every 5 secound ? Maybe its ok because there are only around 300 objects. It would be still interesting to hear if there are more efficient ways to handle this.

Comment: Of course it will :-).  Any program you run will slow the system down for other programs.  But you're talking about 300 integer comparisons on a processor running at gigahertz speeds.  Just refreshing the screen requires millions of operations, and the time required isn't noticeable to the user.

Comment: I found there is a start time information in the psutil.process_iter() object generator. So my new idea would be to seach for an intervall around the current time in the list of a processes  starting times to get the recently  started pcIds. I still feel like there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: Register to get notified on process creation and termination. WMI can be used for this, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was what I was looking for

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()
process_watcher = c.Win32_Process.watch_for("creation")
while True:
    new_process = process_watcher()
    print(new_process.Caption,process.ProcessId)
```

Thank you. I didnt know about WMI.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a complete, working program that does exactly what you asked about.  From start to finish, development time was perhaps 5 minutes.  It should run on any OS that supports python, according to the psutil docs.

I'm on Windows, so I opened the task manager and observed the CPU usage of this program.  It is almost always zero.  Occasionally I see a small value, never more than 3%.

I am sure there is a way to reduce the execution time, for example, see the comment by IInspectable.  Is it worth it, given the ease of development provided by python and psutil?  And do you care if the performance improvement breaks cross-platform compatibility?  Only you can answer those questions, of course.  But unless you are incredibly sensitive to the wasting of a few CPU cycles, I would opt for the simplest solution and move on to something else.

```
#! python3.8

import time

import psutil

old_set = set(list(psutil.process_iter()))
while True:
    new_set = set(list(psutil.process_iter()))
    added = new_set - old_set
    for p in added:
        print("New", p)
    old_set = new_set
    time.sleep(5.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.

the solution I came up with myself very quickly is

```
import psutil
import sched
import time

def checkNewProc():
    for p in psutil.process_iter():
    #print(p.create_time())
        epoch_time =int(time.time())
        if abs(p.create_time()- epoch_time)<2:
            print(p.name(),p.pid)
            
    event_schedule.enter(2, 1, checkNewProc)

event_schedule.enter(2, 1, checkNewProc)

event_schedule.run()
```

The main reason I try to do this is to get a deeper understanding about managing processes. So answers like the one from  IInspectable are what I am looking for to learn new ways to do this things on a deeper level.
I dont care so much about processing time.

So I am still open for different approaches.